# jquery send data perfectly but says internal server error 500 in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am storing data from form in laravel using jquery ajax. It stored data perfectly. But the problem with `success` function. It says `POST http://localhost:8000/insertteammessage 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Here is my route

`Route::post('insertteammessage','PublicController@insertTeamMessage')->name('insertteammessage');`

Here is my controller

```
public function insertTeamMessage(Request $request){
     $this->layout = null;
    if(Request()->ajax()){
        $id = Input::get( 'projectId' );
        $message = Input::get( 'teamMessage' );
        $teamChat =  new TeamChat;
    $teamChat->team_message = $message;
    $teamChat->projectproposal_id = $id;
    $teamChat->user_id = 1;
    $teamChat->unread = 1;
    $teamChat->save();
        $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'successfull',
    );
    return Response::json($response);  
}else{
    return 'no';
}
```

}

Here is my view

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'insertteammessage','id'=>'team-chat')) !!}
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="projectId" name="projectId" value="{{$projectid}}"
        >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teamMessage" name="teamMessage" autofocus>
        <button class="btn btn-success" style="float: right;">Send</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is my Script

```
$('#team-chat').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var teamMessage = $('#teamMessage').val();
   var projectId = $('#projectId').val();
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '{{URL::to("/insertteammessage")}}',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    }
   });
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide some webserver error logs? That should provide details on exactly where the error is occuring.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me by reminding me about webserver error log. Problem was with response. Response facade was not called in the controller that i found by checking laravel.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Problem was with Response facade. I forgot to add this in my controller. After seeing @tudor comment I have checked my error log and found this error. Then I have used `use Response;` in my controller. Now Problem is solved.